# Is possible forward to a JSP custom tag from servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I was wondering if it's possible to forward a response from servlet to a custom tag instead of redirect a response to whole JSP page, here is a code example of what I want to do:

I want to send a request to a servlet from my JSP custom tag:

```
<jsp:forward page="Controller">
     <jsp:param name="Consult" value="${Consult}"/> 
     <jsp:param name="action" value="1"/>
</jsp:forward>
```

Then, after logic has finished I only send a response to my JSP custom tag (Table.tag):

```
request.setAttribute("message", message);
request.getRequestDispatcher("table.tag").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: This looks like XY problem. It would be better if you explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I believe you need [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I want to send a synchronous request to server from a little piece of JSP page, as it was a call to a simple method of a class, but I do not want to use 'scriptlets'. For example, in JSF is possible make this calls separately to Managed Beans methods like this: #{class.method}, and It returns some value. But in my case I'm using JSP-servlets structure and I do not want to reload the whole JSP page for each separate request. I want to know if is it possible?

Comment: If these requests need to come from the client side, then Ajax. If they need to come from the server side, use JSP includes.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to make the request through ajax, I think I was taking an unnecessary way.